# Query cost: Global Temporary Tables vs. Collections (Virtual Arrays)

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance

I have a query whose results are stored in a GTT (Global Temporary Table) and in a Collection.

Selecting the data from the GTT again, I get a very small cost: 103.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM my_table_gtt
JOIN table2 ...
JOIN table3 ...
```

But when switching this from a GTT to a Collection (VA - Virtual Array), the cost skyrockets (78.000), but the difference in execution times between the two is very small.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM TABLE(CAST(my_table_va as my_table_tt))
JOIN table2 ...
JOIN table3 ...
```

My question is why is there such a big difference in cost between the two approaches? From my knowledge, GTTs don't store table statistics, so why is it returning a better cost than the VA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global temporary tables can have statistics as any other table. In fact they are like any other table, they have data segments, just in temporary tablespace.

In 11g the statistics are global so they sometimes cause issues with execution plans. In 12c they are session based so each session gets proper ones (if available).

The collection type cardinality is based on DB block size and for default 8 kB block is 8168. Collection content is stored in PGA. It's quite common to hint the cardinality when using collection types in complex queries to hint the optimizer. You can also use extended optimizer interface for implementing own way for calculating cost.

Edit - added tests:

```
CREATE TYPE STRINGTABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255);
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP (VALUE VARCHAR2(255));

INSERT INTO TMP SELECT 'Value' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000000;

DECLARE
    x STRINGTABLE;
    cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO x FROM TMP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MI:SS.FF3'));

    SELECT SUM(LENGTH(VALUE)) INTO cnt FROM TMP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MI:SS.FF3'));

    SELECT SUM(LENGTH(COLUMN_VALUE)) INTO cnt FROM TABLE(x);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MI:SS.FF3'));
END;
```

In this case is the access to GTT about twice as fast then to collection, cca 200 ms vs. 400 ms on my test machine. When I increased the number of rows to 10 000 000, I got ORA-22813: operand value exceeds system limits on the second query.

Comment: So the collection approach cost would actually display the cost of storing the data in memory, in kB? I'm asking this because I'm trying to compare the performance between the two approaches (execution times are obvious, as they are mostly equal), but are there any other metrics that can be compared?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with it. As far as I know the DB block size is the only thing driving the default cost of a collection. For simple TABLE FULL SCAN the cost is approximately the number of blocks that will be visited. Don't care about the cost that much it's good only for comparison the execution plans of the same query. Much more important is the cardinality of the collection that can affect the execution plan choosing different access paths, join types or join order leading to very unoptimal results.

Comment: So, this would mean that it won't matter the type of "source" I'm querying the data from (GTT or collection) as long as the join order, join type etc. is the same (or best.. ).

Comment: Since GTT is regural data object it can hold lot of data, the collection is in memory object so you are more limited. I haven't made benchmark on it but I assume that until you hit some memory limits it should be similar.

Comment: From what I know the collection stores the data in memory, as long as it fits, and if it doesn't it "spills" the data on the PGA.

Comment: The memory is the PGA. It's the private process memory. Of course the PGA is memory area that holds private data of all the processes. But its part that belongs to single process holds the data of your collection

Comment: "FROM TABLE(x);" - don't forget that you spent time here also to pass collection to SQL engine. While in test with GTT you do not count time to fill it.

Comment: And one more note: in some situations, bind variable peaking allows CBO to get correct cardinality for collections

Answer (score 1):

The most important difference between collections and GTT in SQL, is that CBO(cost-based optimizer) has limitations for TABLE function (kokbf$...), for example JPPD doesn't work with TABLE() functions.
Some workarounds: http://orasql.org/2019/05/30/workarounds-for-jppd-with-view-and-tablekokbf-xmltable-or-json_table-functions/

Comment: Is this actual information? For what version of Oracle DB it works?