# What is the difference between oracle collections and temporary tables?

Tags: oracle

What are the key differences between plsql collections and temporary tables.
Also where exactly are collections stored in oracle database.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654069/query-cost-global-temporary-tables-vs-collections-virtual-arrays

Comment: When asking about the differences, you are probably interested in when to use which. I find this hard to answer. Collections are part of the PL/SQL language. You have associated arrays (called maps in other programming languages) and plain arrays (lists you can also invoke set operations, called MULTISET operators in Oracle, on). And what would a programming language be without arrays? Temporary tables are part of the database; empty tables that you can fill and work with when needed. In very many years using Oracle, I haven't even considered them once the appropriate choice for a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary tables are *tables*; they contain data (during transaction or session, depending on how you create them). Their definition remains in the database (unless you drop it, of course).

Collections can exist

- on PL/SQL level (associative arrays) (so, in RAM) while that PL/SQL procedure is being executed or
- at schema level (varrays and nested tables) (so they are stored in the database and can be referenced by any SQL statements)